# Error with vue - breakpoint not found, mismatch in versions?

Tags: node.js, vue.js, vuetify.js

I upgraded vue from version 2.5.19 to 2.6.11 and now getting these errors.  Were these removed? Any thoughts on error, module doesn't come up with error below

Here is the offending code:

```
<template>
  <v-layout
    row
    justify-center>
    <v-dialog
      :value="dialogOpen"
      scrollable
      persistent
      :fullscreen="$vuetify.breakpoint.xsOnly"
      max-width="600px">
      <v-card class="modal-content" style="align-items:flex-start!important;">
```

vue.runtime.esm.js:619 [Vue warn]: Property or method "$vuetify" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render. Make sure that this property is reactive, either in the data option, or for class-based components, by initializing the property. See: https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#Declaring-Reactive-Properties.

found in

```
---> <Dialog> at node_modules/@my/vue-components/src/components/Dialog/Dialog.vue
       <Header> at src/modules/mapapp/components/Header/Header.vue
         <DashboardLayout> at src/layouts/DashboardLayout.vue
           <App> at src/App.vue
             <Root>
  ...


  vue.runtime.esm.js:619 [Vue warn]: Error in render: "TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'breakpoint')"

found in

---> <Dialog> at node_modules/@my/vue-components/src/components/Dialog/Dialog.vue
       <Header> at src/modules/mapapp/components/Header/Header.vue
         <DashboardLayout> at src/layouts/DashboardLayout.vue
           <App> at src/App.vue
             <Root>
```

...

```
 vue.runtime.esm.js:1888 TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'breakpoint')
    at Proxy.render (Dialog.vue:16:1)
    at Vue._render (vue.runtime.esm.js:3548:1)
    at VueComponent.updateComponent (vue.runtime.esm.js:4066:1)
    at Watcher.get (vue.runtime.esm.js:4479:1)
```

...

```
Dialog.vue:103 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'clientHeight')
    at VueComponent.setScrollStyles (Dialog.vue:103:1)
    at Dialog.vue:95:1
```

...
And package json.

```
{
  "name": "myapp",
  "version": "1.1.7",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "serve": "./serve.sh",
    "build": "vue-cli-service build",
    "lint": "vue-cli-service lint",
    "test:unit": "vue-cli-service test:unit --no-cache"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@my/vue-components": "0.1.230",
    "@vue/eslint-config-airbnb": "^4.0.1",
    "axios": "0.21.2",
    "babel-polyfill": "6.26.0",
    "core-util-is": "^1.0.2",
    "lodash": "^4.17.15",
    "moment": "2.29.2",
    "vue": "2.6.11",
    "vue-cookies": "^1.5.13",
    "vue-i18n": "8.15.1",
    "vue-router": "3.1.3",
    "vue-template-compiler": "2.6.11",
    "vuelidate": "0.7.4",
    "vuetify": "1.2.1",
    "vuex": "3.0.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-optional-chaining": "^7.7.5",
    "@babel/polyfill": "^7.7.0",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.7.7",
    "@kazupon/vue-i18n-loader": "^0.3.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-babel": "^4.2.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-eslint": "^4.2.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-unit-jest": "^4.2.0",
    "@vue/cli-service": "^4.2.0",
    "@vue/test-utils": "^1.0.0-beta.29",
    "babel-core": "^7.0.0-bridge.0",
    "babel-eslint": "^8.2.6",
    "babel-jest": "^23.0.1",
    "eslint": "^6.7.2",
    "eslint-plugin-vue": "^6.1.2",
    "html-loader": "^0.5.5",
    "jest-raw-loader": "^1.0.1",
    "lint-staged": "^7.3.0",
    "raw-loader": "^3.1.0",
    "stylus": "^0.54.5",
    "stylus-loader": "^3.0.2",
    "vue-cli-plugin-i18n": "^0.6.1",
    "vue-cli-plugin-vuetify": "^0.6.3",
    "vue-loader": "^15.8.3",
    "vue-template-compiler": "2.6.11",
    "handlebars": "4.5.0"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `$vuetify` object should still be injected (or already, considering that it seems to be v1):

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data(){
    return {
      vueVersion: Vue.version,
      vuetifyVersion: Vuetify.version
    }
  },
})
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@1.2.1/dist/vuetify.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

  <div id="app">
    <v-app>
      <div>Vue version: {{vueVersion}}</div>
      <div>Vuetify version: {{vuetifyVersion}}</div>
      <div>$vuetify.breakpoint: {{$vuetify.breakpoint}}</div>
    </v-app>
  </div>

  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.6.11/dist/vue.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@1.2.1/dist/vuetify.js"></script>
```

Make sure that Vuetify is loaded at all, if it isn't, accessing the `$vuetify` property is probably one of the earliest errors you would get.

Comment: I like the idea of testing the values, but this more of a node build issue.  Why aren't those values injected but I will look at your post.